# Multiple itemlisteners in a single class

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I am new to Java and Swing and am following [zetcode tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/basicswingcomponents/). I want to add multiple `JComboBox`es and store the index selected for each one of those. `index1` should hold selected index from 1st instance of `JComboBox` and `index2` should hold selected index from 2nd instance of `JComboBox`. For one `JComboBox` it can be done like this:

```
public ComboBox() {

    setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), 
    BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 35)));

    combobox = new JComboBox(authors);
    combobox.addItemListener(this);
    add(combobox);
}
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        JComboBox combo = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        int index = combo.getSelectedIndex();
        display.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
            ClassLoader.getSystemResource(images[index])));
    }

}
```

So if I could write the name of itemlistener that should be called for each `JComboBox` and then instead of writing `combobox.addItemListener(this)`, I could write `combobox.addItemListener(itemListener1)`. How do I do this?

Comment: Any class that implements the ItemListener interface can be passed to `addItemListener(ItemListener)`. It is common to see this interface implemented by the `JPanel` or `JFrame` that contains the `JComboBox`, such as in the example in the tutorial mentioned. If you want to provide separate `ItemListener`s for separate `JComboBox`es, then you'd need to implement a new class that uses this interface.

Comment: but why do i need a new class for each `JComboBox`, when one suffices and i can get required functionality.

Comment: You might, you might not. Depends on what you are trying to achieve. @sam's answer provides a sufficient method for achieving the desired functionality.

Comment: yes, i am using sam's code itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing like this

```
combobox1.addItemListener(this);
combobox2.addItemListener(this);
..
comboboxn.addItemListener(this);
```

---

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 if(e.getSource().equals(comboBox1))
 {
  \\do something
 }
 else if(e.getSource().equals(comboBox2))
 {
  \\do something
 }
..
 else if(e.getSource().equals(comboBoxn))
 {
  \\do something
 }
```

Comment: thanks. And don't I need a line like `if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use inner or anonymous classes, it helps to avoid 'if - else' statements.

[Exemple](http://java.about.com/od/Handling-Events/ss/Itemlistener-Example-Code-Program.htm)! of anonymous class

Comment: your answer too seems fine but well my code just got working with the above one too.